# Not able to find Spring "classpath:" location

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a Spring Project where I am using bean configuration file
`beans.xml`.Inside the bean Configuration file, i have defined some properties for a PlaceHolder which refers to classPath...While the application is running, the properties are getting loaded from `/unknownPath/Dev/Loc1/System.properties`

Where

```
${BUS_ENV}=Dev
${LOCATION1}=Loc1
```

---

```
<bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:${BUS_ENV}/${LOCATION1}/system.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:${BUS_ENV}/lbsprocessor.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <!-- Force system properties to override any deployed runtime properties -->
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />

</bean>
```

1. I didn't specify classpath while running my project in IDE
2. I don't have those files in my resource folder
3. There are around 65 such files exists(for various reasons) as `Dev/Loc1/System.properties`
4. I am not able to find from which location the properties are getting referred. Even after debugging, I couldn't find out what classpath refers to. Please help me with figuring out

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse IDE right click on your project select properties then select Java Build Path. On first tab Source there is one input named Default Output folder that value is your classpath. Check all your properties files are there in that path.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your `point 2` problems might be in these line

```
<value>classpath:${BUS_ENV}/${LOCATION1}/system.properties</value>
<value>classpath:${BUS_ENV}/lbsprocessor.properties</value>
```

You are using `classpath` for file location which means these properties file have to be in the .war file at `/Dev/Loc1/System.properties`

If properties files are outside of project may be at system level you can access them like this

```
<value>file:${BUS_ENV}/${LOCATION1}/system.properties</value>
<value>file:${BUS_ENV}/lbsprocessor.properties</value>
```

eg:

```
<value>file:/home/testuser/system.properties</value>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mac OS ,in this we are storing the Configurations as a jar file under 
/Library/Java/Extension.So java is directly referring classpath to that location by default.

Comment: From terminal run this command  " echo $CLASSPATH" you will get classpath or open using any archive tool you can view all your properties file under classes folder of your war/jar